# Points of intersection of two circles

Tags: geometry

We have two circles $x^2 + y^2 = \alpha x$ and $x^2 + y^2 = \beta y $ for any $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to find the points of intersection.

We know $(0,0)$ is trivially a solution. If we set the equations the same, we get $y = \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta} x $ so we have

$$ x^2 + \left( \frac{ \alpha x }{\beta} \right)^2 = \alpha x \implies x + \frac{ \alpha^2}{\beta^2}x = \alpha \implies x = \frac{\beta^2 \alpha}{\beta^2 + \alpha^2}$$

and so $y = \frac{ \beta \alpha^2}{\beta^2 + \alpha^2} $. So we get another point of intersection. Is this correct solution?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct solution, as you can easily check by substituting back into the original equations of the circles. [2nd one should be ... =, not ... +]

Comment: @Learner That is the correct second point. How do you check this? Well, you just need to check that the equations hold. Insert your values for $x$ and $y$ into both circle equations, and you'll see that they are both true.

Comment: and the second equation is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for two circles:
$$
(x-h_1)^2+(y-k_1)^2=r_1^2\quad\text{and}\quad(x-h_2)^2+(y-k_2)^2=r_2^2,
$$
their difference is a linear equation.
$$
2(h_2-h_1)x+2(k_2-k_1)+(h_1^2-h_2^2)+(k_1^2-k_2^2)=r_1^2-r_2^2.
$$
The line determined by this equation passes through the two intersection points of the spheres (even if the intersection point is a double intersection or a complex intersection).  Then, the points of interest are triple intersections of the circles and the line; if you solve for $x$ or $y$ and plug that value into one of the circles, the two solutions will be the two intersection points.