# Quadrilateral with 2 known coordinates, one known edge vector and 4 known lengths, what are the missing coordinates?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

I'm doing some generative design for architecture and I can't quite get my high school geometry over the line on this one. I have filled pages with pythagoras; I must be ignorant of a more powerful method:

[Simple diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjjkR.png)

[image]

I know all four lengths of a convex quadrilateral, AB, BC, CD, DE.
I know the coordinates of A and B
I know that CD is flat ie. it has a normalized vector of (1,0,0)
I need to find the coordinates of C and D (they share Y values)

(I'm aware that there are two solutions either side of AB, but it will be trivial to know which one I want)

Comment: It looks like you know about Cartesian coordinates, and treating the coordinates as unknowns is powerful enough to work out all the possible solutions.  Count how many unknowns there are in your problem (recalling that $X_A,X_B,Y_A,Y_B$ are *known*), and start with equations for the conditions imposed on the remaining unknowns.

Answer (score 4):

Let $B'(X_B + CD, Y_B)$ be the point obtained by translating $B$ to the right by a distance equal to the (known) distance $CD$. Because the same translation takes $C$ to $D$, we know that $B'D = BC$.

Therefore $D$ must be the point at distance $AD$ from $A$ and at distance $BC$ from $B'$: it is the intersection of two circles whose center and radius we know.

Solving for that intersection point *can* boil down to an equation in coordinates, starting from the equation of a circle with radius $r$ and center $(h,k)$: $$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2.$$ You can find discussions of that problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771390) for example. Briefly, subtracting the equations of the two circles gives a linear equation, which you can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ (or vice versa), and then substitute into one of the circle equations to get a quadratic equation.

Depending on your situation, you might have other ways to find the intersection of two circles, such as by using a compass to draw the circles and mark the intersection :)

Comment: Yes, of course, by subtracting CD from B, it's simple circle intersection. The sort of thing that should have come to me in the shower. Thank you.